# What is (best) way to unit test native part in cordova plugin?

Tags: cordova, unit-testing, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

The plugin folder will have only the source files of native code. In this case,
just would like to know the (best) way to unit test native part in cordova plugin?
Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additional plugin containing Jasmine tests, which will be calling your plugin interface (i.e. JS -> plugin proxy -> Native code), and then run it with cordova-paramedic.

Example test plugin:

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/tests/plugin.xml
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device/blob/master/tests/tests.js

`mkdir test
cd test
npm install cordova-paramedic
cordova-paramedic --platform windows --plugin ../your-cordova-plugin-name`

You can then run tests for different platforms and even use SauceLabs for CI.

Comment: I can understand that we can test native via JS interface but is there any way to test native directly? Are there any industry practice. Googled quite some time but didn't find any.

Comment: For native tests example solutions refer to https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/master/test and https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/tree/master/tests/ios

Comment: Also: `cordova.exec (<successFunction>, <failFunction> , <service> , <action> , [< args >]);` could be used to call the plugin directly. @EaswaramoorthyK - extend your question if this does not answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain separate android project to unit test native code

1. extract your plugins native java files in separate android library project in
   android studio
2. write unit tests for java files in this android library
3. after passing all testcases move this java files into plugin package